# Anyway for admin to get ALL checkin info?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, checkin, facebook-checkins

looks like every checkin call on the api only relates to a user's checkins or their friends.  Is there no way for a page administrator to see all of their checkins with times and names?  I know you can see the total, but we are needing to look for a new checkin to the page every hour.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this in the API or on the page itself.

If you want to track if/when a specific user checks in (e.g. for a promotion) you'd need to get the user to authorise an application with sufficient permissions for the app to see their checkins

Comment: Can't believe they haven't implemented this, its standard across all of the other checkin services.  Oh well, thanks for your help!